# Downloading/Copying File from SFTP via PSCP using VBA

Tags: vba, download, sftp, putty

I am having some struggles getting a script working. I have downloaded PuTTY package that comes with PSCP.exe which I intend to use to download/copy files from an SFTP server and either save them or write them to my local drive.

Below is the skeleton of an upload script that I altered to download instead.

I am getting the following error when I attempt to run the script:

```
Windows Script Host
    Script: C:\Script.txt
    Line: 2
    Char: 20
    Error: Expected '='
    Code: 800A03F3
    Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

-T

```
 Sub SftpGet()
    Const cstrSftp As String = """C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"""
    Dim strCommand As String
    Dim pUser As String
    Dim pPass As String
    Dim pHost As String
    Dim pFile As String
    Dim pRemotePath As String

    pUser = "USER" '//User on remote system
    pPass = "PASSWORD" '//User's password on remote system
    pHost = "SFTP.WEBSITE.ORG" '//Ip address of remote system
    pFile = "C:\Important_Info_Copy.txt" '//File to write copy of "pRemotePath" to
    pRemotePath = "/Important_Info.txt" '//Location of file to copy

    strCommand = cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath &_
        " " & pFile &
    Debug.Print strCommand
    Shell strCommand, 1 ' vbNormalFocus '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In your title you say "VBA", while you seem to run your code as VBScript. There are distinct languages.

AFAIK, VBScript (as opposite to VBA) does not support typed variables. So remove all `As Type` pieces:

```
Const cstrSftp = """C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"""
Dim strCommand
Dim pUser
Dim pPass
Dim pHost
Dim pFile
Dim pRemotePath
```

2) You are definitely missing a space between password and host. `pPass & pHost` should be `pPass & " " & pHost`.

3) Remote the trailing `&` from the `strCommand` assembly line

4) Also some quoting would make your code more robust. Though with your current inputs, it cannot cause your troubles as you are not having any spaces in them.

5) Also not sure that VBScript has `Shell` statement/command

Answer (score 0):

I use something called Active Experts with VBScript in order to be able to upload / download files from a Sun Solaris box.

Download can be found at:
http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/objects/sftp/

Once downloaded, you can reference the "ActiveXperts.SFtp" object and perform file transfers via VBScript. Example code snippet below:

```
' -----------------------------------------
' Method: doFTPAction()
' Descrip: upload or download a file
' -----------------------------------------
Private Function doFTPAction(p_strAction,_
                             p_strFTPLogFile,_
                             p_strIP,_
                             p_strPort,_
                             p_strUsername,_
                             p_strPassword,_
                             p_strRemoteDirectory,_
                             p_strFileSource,_ 'fully qualified name to source file
                             p_strFileTarget) ' fully qualified name to target file
    Dim blnIsOK
    Dim objSFtp
    Dim strReturnCode

    blnIsOK = False
    Set objSFtp = CreateObject("ActiveXperts.SFtp")

    'setup and connect to the remote server
    objSFtp.Clear  
    objSFtp.Host = p_strIP
    objSFtp.Port = p_strPort
    objSFtp.UserName = p_strUsername
    objSFtp.Password = p_strPassword
    objSFtp.PrivateKeyFile = ""
    objSFtp.LogFile = p_strFTPLogFile
    objSFtp.AcceptHostKey = True
    objSFtp.Connect


    Select Case p_strAction
        Case "DOWNLOAD_FILE"
            strReturnCode = objSFtp.GetFile ("" & p_strFileSource & "", "" & p_strFileTarget & "")
        Case "UPLOAD_FILE"
            strReturnCode = objSFtp.PutFile ("" & p_strFileSource & "", "" & p_strFileTarget & "")
    End Select

    'cleanup
    objSFtp.Disconnect
    Set objSFtp = Nothing

    doFTPAction = blnIsOK
End Function
```